# How do I remove the space between links?

Tags: html, css

```
<nav id="main_nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

#main_nav{
    background:green;
}

#main_nav li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#main_nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
}

#main_nav li{
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, background .5s, color .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s, background .5s, color .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s, background .5s, color .5s;
}

#main_nav li:hover{
    color:red;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 200,.5);
}
```

This is my navigation bar, but I have a problem. Between each link is a small space. When I hover over them quickly, it doesn't look nice. How do I remove it?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle for the same. Makes it easier for anyone to answer the question more appropriately.

Comment: Are you using a css reset? If not simple set margin and padding on every thing i.e. "*" to 0 and work from there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few ways:

- Remove the white space between the list items ( **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7NvGa/)**)
- Use comments (`<!-- -->`) to occupy the white space gap (**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7NvGa/1/)**)
- Close the list item tags on the next line (**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7NvGa/2/)**)

Note that there's also a fourth option where you can set the font-size to zero on the `#main_nav` element, and then set the font-size on the anchors to something larger, but there have been issues with some earlier builds of Android with this technique. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7NvGa/4/)**.

Comment: All your examples are good, but there may be a situation where the html is generated by a CMS (e.g. WordPress) and it is difficult to modify without using hooks/filters. In this instance a CSS-Only solution might be superior.

Comment: I've found that using comments `<!-- -->` is the cleanest way to remove spaces when using `span` and `a` tags to break up your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

it happens when you use `display:inline-block;` for list element. 
you should use `float:left` or play with margins/paddings

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zteA7/

It is because of inline-block creating space.

Make the `<li>` element floated and use the CSS `:after` selector to insert a clearer block element to make the `nav` block the height that of the menu. (no html required).

You also don't need to specify the container heights which should mean line-breaks will work

Comment: Wow, loads of answers. Looks like mine is probably not the best, unless your html is generated by a cms and you can't remove the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Arrange **`all the list in single line`** will remove the space...

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">About Us</a></li><li><a href="#">Forum</a></li><li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/78/

Answer (score 0):

```
#main_nav li{
    display:inline-block;  /* the new web designer disease ?? */
    list-style:none;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0;
}
```

Just rewrite your html this way

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">About Us</a></li><li><a href="#">Forum</a></li><li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the property `display: inline-block;`, which causes the `li` "blocks" to still behave as inline elements, and therefore build spaces between them. I've had this problem a couple of times and I know two (not so beatiful) solutions:

1. Make the `li` elements `float: left`, but be careful to not mess up the rest of your design.
2. Write space-filling html comments between the `li` elements, so no "space" is recognized between them by the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Remove any padding from your <ul> tag. It might be useful for you to use a reset.css to avoid problems like this http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/